# Rails fragment that needs caching for 5 minutes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

These are some lines I have in Rails:

```
@quickbar_posts = []
SETTINGS[:news_groups].each do |group_short_name|
  @quickbar_posts << quickbar_posts(group_short_name)
end
```

What I would like is that variable @quickbar_posts to be cached in memory for 5 minutes OR for the final output of the function quickbar_posts (after it has exited the for-loop) to be saved locally in the filesystem for 5 minutes.

My problem is that every time this is run, it's highly inefficient for this to be fetched every time, so I just want it saved for 5 minutes, then fetched again, invalidating the previously cached item if the age of the cached item is > 5 minutes.

In addition, adding or changing gems is not possible - since this code is running in production and for reasons that can't be explained here, nothing else can be changed in production.

Comment: Are you running a cache backend that supports expiration times on production, such as memcached or redis?

Comment: @infused no - nothing at all. The only thing available is either in-memory or the local filesystem. It's primitive. Perhaps the local filesystem could be a workable option, but needs cache invalidation written manually, given that no extra gems or any other changes are possible. The reason for this question is mainly because I am so highly restricted in what I can do to optimise this fragment.

Comment: Did you try with Rails.cache? it allows both in-memory and filesystem and also supports expires_in. Give a look: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html

Comment: What version of Rails are you running?

Comment: @infused it's Ruby Enterprise 1.8.7

Comment: What version is Rails?

Comment: Sorry, it's 3.0.11 for Rails

Answer (score -1):

`ActiveSupport` part of Rails allows to use cache.

You should verify that cache is enabled so in `config/enviroments/production.rb` you should set the following flag:

```
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
```

To cache `@quickbar_posts` for 5 minutes, you can use the following code:

```
@quickbar_posts = Rails.cache.fetch("quickbar_posts", expires_in: 5.minutes) do
    SETTINGS[:news_groups].map{|group_short_name| quickbar_posts(group_short_name)}
end
```

Ruby 1.8.7 syntax:

```
@quickbar_posts = Rails.cache.fetch("quickbar_posts", :expires_in => 5.minutes) do
    SETTINGS[:news_groups].map{|group_short_name| quickbar_posts(group_short_name)}
end
```

You can use different cache stores, to set the one you want, you can do it in `config/application.rb` on in `config/environments/your_environment.rb` (production/test/deploy)

To use *ActiveSupport::Cache::MemoryStore*:

```
config.cache_store = :memory_store
```

To use *ActiveSupport::Cache::FileStore*:

```
config.cache_store = :file_store, "/path/to/cache/directory"
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I just tried it and it doesn't seem to work for me. The Ruby Enterprise version used in this production instance is 1.8.7 in case it helps

Comment: Weird, based on rails 3.0 source code it should works: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-0-stable/activesupport/lib/active_support/cache.rb

Comment: @AmitKothari, the syntax I've used is not supported in ruby 1.8.7, I've updated the answer to add the correct syntax for you ruby version